# Why my main container too wide? Just a col-9 and col-3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a page with a col-3 to the left and col-9 to the right, with a nav in the col-3 and jumbotron, along with text in the col-9, but for some reason the page comes out way too wide, wherein a scrollbar is necessary to navigate the full width of the page.

Haven't really tried much other than googling which hasn't yielded any results.

````
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-sm-3">

      </div><!--closing of left column-->

  <div class = "col-sm-9">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-sm-12 text-center">
          <div class = "row text-center">
            <h1>Oregon Tulip Festival</h1>
          </div>
  <div class = "jumbotron img-responsive">
  <div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-12">
  <p class = "jumbo">Sunset at the Tulip Festival</p>
        </div>
    </div>
          </div>
        </div><!--closing of jumbotron-->
<hr>
<h2>Tulip festival | Experience Oregon's finest tulip arrangement</h2>
</div>
    </div><!--closing of small container-->

  </div><!--closing of right column-->
</div>
</div><!--closing of large container-->
</div>```

I have all the divs closed off, so I don't really know how to eliminate the unnecessary width. Could it possibly be my jumbotron?
````

Comment: Two things should fix your problem. One, your code example here is missing the very topmost <div class="container">. Two, change all of your <div class="container"> to <div class="container-fluid">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use container multiple times for this layout, try the below HTML structure. I hope this structure will help you.

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-sm-3">
    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-9">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-sm-12 text-center">
                <div class = "row text-center">
                    <h1>Oregon Tulip Festival</h1>
                </div>
                <div class = "jumbotron img-responsive">
                    <div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-sm-12">
                            <p class = "jumbo">Sunset at the Tulip Festival</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <h2>Tulip festival | Experience Oregon's finest tulip arrangement</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @GabrielYin-Dolvig can you please approve or upvote my answer?